# generic Number class refactoring?

Tags: python, class, refactoring

I just made a generic number class.

this class is so simple, descriptions are below

- from any ordered character list, make number class representing that ordered character list.
- `create_number_class("01")` returns binary number class
- `create_number_class("0123456789")` returns decimal number class
- `create_number_class("abcdefghij")` return decimal number class but representing each digit as a alphabet.

belows is generic number class definition.

I think it is well-made class definition.

are there something needed improvement in that class definition?

thank you all. always.

ex)

```
ABC_Class = create_number_class("abc")
x = ABC_Class("baa")
y = ABC_Class("bbb")
print(x+y)
#output digits: abc, v: cbb, decimal_v: 22
```

below is class definition

```
def create_number_class(alphabet):
    class temp(object):
        digits = alphabet
        def __init__(self, v):
            self.v = v
            self.decimal_v = self.to_decimal(self)
        @staticmethod
        def to_decimal(self):
            r = 0
            for i in range(0, len(self.v)):
                r += len(temp.digits)**(len(self.v)-i-1)*(temp.digits.index(self.v[i]))
            return r
        @classmethod
        def from_decimal(cls, decimal_v):
            r = []
            mod = len(temp.digits)
            if decimal_v < mod:
                return cls(temp.digits[decimal_v])
            while True:
                remainder = decimal_v % mod
                r.append(remainder)
                decimal_v = int((decimal_v - remainder)/ mod)
                if decimal_v < mod:
                    r.append(decimal_v)
                    break
            r = "".join(list(reversed([temp.digits[x] for x in r])))
            #r = "".join(list(reversed([str(temp.digits.index(str(x))) for x in r])))
            return cls(r)
        def __add__(self, other):
            return temp.from_decimal(self.decimal_v+other.decimal_v)
        def __sub__(self, other):
            return temp.from_decimal(self.decimal_v-other.decimal_v)
        def __mul__(self, other):
            return temp.from_decimal(self.decimal_v*other.decimal_v)
        def __floordiv__(self, other):
            return temp.from_decimal(self.decimal_v//other.decimal_v)
        def __str__(self):
            return "digits: {}, v: {}, decimal_v: {}".format(temp.digits, self.v, self.decimal_v)
        def convert_to(self, new_class):
            return new_class.from_decimal(self.decimal_v)
    return temp
```

below are example

```
BinClass = create_number_class("01")
DecimalClass = create_number_class("0123456789")

x = BinClass("111")
x = BinClass("1000")
y = BinClass("10")

HexClass = create_number_class('0123456789ABCDEF')
x = HexClass('1')
y = HexClass('AA')

print(x+y)
print(x-y)
print(x*y)
print(x//y)
print(x.convert_to(DecimalClass))
isinstance(x, BinClass)
```

Comment: Hi frhyme, reading your question, I think it belongs more to another comunity of stack exange, better ask here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I don't know that kind of site. Thank you.